# Prevent empty console input from user in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

Hi I would like to prevent users from entering nothing in the input field.

I've tried using an if else but the console keeps crashing when there's no input. (for both user input and ldap address input ==> I want it to show "No input detected." and allow the user to re-enter the username)

And if I used `(results == " ")`, I would get a  error:

> "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult' and 'string'"

Is there any way for me to resolve this? The codes are as shown below.

**Affected codes from line 16 onwards (for the top block of codes)**

```
if (results != null)
{
    //Check is account activated
    bool isAccountActived = IsActive(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

    if (isAccountActived) 
        Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is active.");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is inactive.");

    //Check is account expired or locked
    bool isAccountLocked = IsAccountLockOrExpired(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

    if (isAccountLocked) 
        Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is locked or has expired.");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is not locked or expired.");

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n\n");
}                               
else if (results == " ")
{ 
     //no user entered
    Console.WriteLine("No input detected!");
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
}
else 
{
    //user does not exist
    Console.WriteLine("User not found!");
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
}
```

If it helps, I've attached the whole code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const String serviceAccountUserName = "mobileuser1";
        const String serviceAccountPassword = "password123$";
        const int UF_LOCKOUT = 0x0010;
        const int UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to account validator V1.0.\n"+"Please enter the ldap address to proceed.");
            Console.Write("\nEnter address: ");
            String ldapAddress = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            { 
                if (ldapAddress != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuerying for users in " + ldapAddress);
                    //start of do-while
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the user's account name to proceed.");
                        Console.Write("\nUsername: ");
                        String targetUserName = Console.ReadLine();

                        bool isValid = false;

                        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapAddress))
                        {
                            // validate the credentials
                            isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

                            // search AD data
                            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ldapAddress, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

                            //create instance fo the directory searcher
                            DirectorySearcher desearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                            //set the search filter
                            desearch.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + targetUserName + ")(objectcategory=user))";

                            //find the first instance
                            SearchResult results = desearch.FindOne();

                            if (results != null)
                            {

                                //Check is account activated
                                bool isAccountActived = IsActive(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                                if (isAccountActived) Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is active.");

                                else Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is inactive.");


                                //Check is account expired or locked
                                bool isAccountLocked = IsAccountLockOrExpired(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                                if (isAccountLocked) Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is locked or has expired.");

                                else Console.WriteLine(targetUserName + "'s account is not locked or expired.");


                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
                                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n\n");
                            }
                            else if (results == " ")
                            { 
                                 //no user entered
                                Console.WriteLine("No input detected!");
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
                                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                //user does not exist
                                Console.WriteLine("User not found!");
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
                                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
                            }

                        }//end of using                          
                    }//end of do 

                    //leave console when 'bye' is entered
                    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "bye");

                }//end of if for ldap statement
                else if (ldapAddress == " ")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No input detected.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Address not found!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter bye to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.\n");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }//end of try
            catch (Exception e)  
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());  
            }
        } //end of main void

        static private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
        {
            if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;

            int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

            return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
        }

        static private bool IsAccountLockOrExpired(DirectoryEntry de)
        {
            string attribName = "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed";
            de.RefreshCache(new string[] { attribName });
            int userFlags = (int)de.Properties[attribName].Value;

            return userFlags == UF_LOCKOUT || userFlags == UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input));

Comment: Hi utility, thanks for answering my question.

Comment: did that solve issue?,if was helpful mark as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `ReadLine` in a loop.

```
string UserName = "";
do {
    Console.Write("Username: ");
    UserName = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)) {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty input, please try again");
    }
} while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName));
```

You basically repeat the prompt over and over until the string entered by the user is no longer null or empty.
Best method would probably be to create a new function to get a non empty input:

```
private static string GetInput(string Prompt)
{
    string Result = "";
    do {
        Console.Write(Prompt + ": ");
        Result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Result)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty input, please try again");
        }
    } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Result));
    return Result;
}
```

You can then just use the function to get your inputs like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetInput("Username");
    GetInput("Password");
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Jens, how do I use GetInput inside my "static void Main(string[] args)" method? When I try to call it, I get a "An object reference is needed for the non static field, method or property" error. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It will be better if you prevent user to entry only spaces. Otherwise this is the best approach!

Comment: @coder123 Sorry. CodeInNet is correct, you need to mark the function as static as well. It was a translation from VB.NET where this got lost.

Comment: @CodeInNet But it's just an assumption that `"_ _ _ _"` (spaces) is not a valid input string. Validation of the input is another question entirely and may rely on context anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code :

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input));
```

Comment: What about for an integer?

Answer (score 0):

This is user first name and last name string

```
 //Make container for the user first name and last name
 string myFirstName = "";
 string myLastName = "";

 //Do while loop
 do
 {
//Welcomes user to the app and asks for first name then asks for last name
Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
Console.WriteLine("Enter first name: ");

//Takes users first name and last name and saves it in myFirstName and myLastName
myFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter Last name: ");
myLastName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();
   
//If the first AND (&&) last name is not empty because the user entered first name and last name then display the hello message
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myFirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myLastName))
{
    
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + myFirstName + " " + myLastName + " hope you enjoy your day");       
}
else //Else the first name or last name is left empty then display the error message
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name and last name");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

//While if either the first name OR (||) last name is empty then keep asking the user for input
} while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myFirstName) || 
string.IsNullOrEmpty(myLastName));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

[image]